# Angularjs - Resize bootstrap modal after modal is shown

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angular-ui-bootstrap

I am still fairly new to angularjs and am currently porting a existing spa javascript application to the angularjs framework. I am using the ui-bootstrap directive for creating bootstrap modals. I am trying to re-position the modal in the middle of the screen once the modal is displayed on the screen. With jQuery that was a easy task, just grab the modal element after calling:

```
$('#modal').modal('show')
```

But I can't seem to figure out the correct way to do this using angular. My first thought was to catch bootstrap events. But it turns out those are not fired according to 
[Here](https://github.com/angular-ui/bootstrap/issues/3247)
 and
[Here](https://github.com/angular-ui/bootstrap/issues/2549)

I tried creating a custom directive, but in the link function the element was defined but was not visible on the screen yet. I need a way to trigger some resize code once the modal is visible.

I also tried accessing the `$modalStack.getTop()`, but I end up having the same issue. There is no way to know when `$modalStack.getTop().value.modalDomEl` is actually resolved and showing on the screen.

I also tried the following, but the opened promise is resolved before the modal is actually showing on the screen.

```
modalInstance.opened.then(function(t){
   //$modalStack.getTop()
});
```

How do you accomplish this using angular?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So I ended up taking what @user2943490 recommended and tweaked it a little bit for my use case.

I created a directive that I added to the Modal Template. Inside I check every 100ms to see if the modal-content class exists. If the class exists we know that the modal has bee added to the DOM. Once I perform my logic, I cancel the $interval check.

```
    return {
        link: function(scope, element, attrs){

            var checkInterval = $interval(checkDOM, 100);

            function checkDOM(){
                var $content = element.find('.modal-content');

                if($content.length){
                   //We know if $content.length > 0 Then the modal-content class exists on the screen.
                $interval.cancel(checkInterval);

                }
            }

      element.on('$destroy', function(){
          $interval.cancel(checkInterval);
      });
```

Comment: Worked great to re-size a modal on rendering to keep it from overflowing the window.

Answer (score 0):

You should use CSS to position the modal as a first option. This avoids all issues around the timing of when specific elements get rendered and stays in line with Angular's spirit of using data binding rather than manual DOM manipulation to build your UI.

You won't find many things in the Angular world that give you an "element rendered" event or similar. It's just not the recommended way to do things.

If you absolutely cannot use CSS, then use a $timeout within the opened promise, and wait a short time (50ms is probably fine) before executing your repositioning logic.

```
modalInstance.opened.then(function(t){
    $timeout(function () {
        // reposition it
    }, 50);
});
```

Comment: I've give the $timeout a try, just seems a little hackish to me.

Comment: it is, that's why you should minimise code that relies on waiting for elements to render

Answer (score 0):

You should have used modal.rendered instead of modal.opened. No need for a link function or interval checks or anything else.

```
modalInstance.rendered.then(function () {
   $('.modal-content').css({ 'width': $(document).width() - 100 + 'px' });     
});
```

Comment: At the time of the original question, I don't believe the rendered event was even created yet. But yes, this would probably be a better solution given the available events now.